# RColorBrewer space out palletes

Tags: r, colorbrewer

I'm new to R and I can't really understand graphs yet.

```
library(RColorBrewer)

display.brewer.all(n=NULL, type="all", select=NULL, exact.n=TRUE, 
                   colorblindFriendly=TRUE)
```

[image: Output]

This is the output. How do I space out elements?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same corrupted output.

But if you work in RStudio - the imposition after zooming is disappeared.

Also you can try:

```
windows()
display.brewer.all(n=NULL, type="all", select=NULL, exact.n=TRUE, 
                   colorblindFriendly=TRUE)
```

or

```
library(zoom)
display.brewer.all(n=NULL, type="all", select=NULL, exact.n=TRUE, 
                   colorblindFriendly=TRUE)
zm()
```